# React final form - Validation return key & value instead of string

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

Currently I am using React-Final-Form and I want to return an object or key/value instead of an error string.

This is my validation rule:

```
validate={values => {
        const errors = {}
        if (!values.username) {
          errors.username = 'Required'
        }
        if (!values.password) {
          errors.password = 'Required'
        }
        if (!values.confirm) {
          errors.confirm = 'Required'
        } else if (values.confirm !== values.password) {
          errors.confirm = 'Must match'
        }
        return errors
      }}
```

This prints the error:

```
  {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
```

Instead of seeing Required I want to be able to say: key -> 'required' and the value of this key is 'please fill in the field'. I know it is possible to change the string of 'Required' but I want to have a key value. I cannot make an object it won't allow me.

Desired result:
{meta.error && meta.touched && {meta.error.required}}

**UI will show:**
Please fill in the field

This playground of react-final-form can be used since it is almost the same:

https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/record-level-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do it like this:

```
  <Form
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      validate={values => {
        const errors = {}
        if (!values.username) {
          errors.username = { required: true, text: "Please fill in the field"} // this is used as an object
        }
        if (!values.password) {
          errors.password = 'Required'
        }
        if (!values.confirm) {
          errors.confirm = 'Required'
        } else if (values.confirm !== values.password) {
          errors.confirm = 'Must match'
        }
        return errors
      }}
      render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Field name="username">
            {({ input, meta }) => {
              console.log(meta) // to see the structure of your meta
              return (
              <div>
                <label>Username</label>
                <input {...input} type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error.text}</span>}
// then here if you still want to use string you can put what you need
                  </div>
                )}}
              </Field>
              <Field name="password">
                {({ input, meta }) => (
                  <div>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input {...input} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    {meta.error && meta.touched && meta.required && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
                  </div>
                )}
              </Field>
              <Field name="confirm">
                {({ input, meta }) => (
                  <div>
                    <label>Confirm</label>
                    <input {...input} type="password" placeholder="Confirm" />
                    {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
                  </div>
                )}
              </Field>
              <div className="buttons">
                <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
                  Submit
                </button>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={form.reset}
                  disabled={submitting || pristine}
                >
                  Reset
                </button>
              </div>
              <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2)}</pre>
            </form>
          )}
        />
```

Comment: I had the same solution by making an object but it failed. Than I tried yours but it worked. I guess i did something wrong.